# How to re-install Thunderbird

Tags: uninstall

I have Thunderbird installed.
I would like/need to re-install it completely.
I do  not see any option to do it in Settings or anywhere.

Also, I can't find a Menu entry or equivalent to remove an account from Thunderbird.
That is the reason I need to re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also completely remove everything by deleting .thunderbird folder from your home directory.

```
rm -rf ~/.thunderbird
```

Thunderbird will act like it was just installed.
If you open folder in Nautilus, it might not show up because it is hidden. You have to press CTRL + H to show hidden (starts with .) files and folders.

Comment: Note this will completly obiliterate any mail, settings, etc stored on that users screen. It may also be in `~/.mozilla/thunderbird`...

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to remove an e-Mail account, go in "Edit" menu, then "Account Settings...". Select the account you wish to remove, then click on "Account Actions" and then "Remove account".

If you wish to reconfigure Thunderbird from scratch, just as if you were launching it for the very first time, you should simply remove the hidden folder ".thunderbird" which is located in your home folder. WARNING: If you use POP3 and don't keep a copy of all your e-mails on the server, you'll loose all of them if you don't have any backup!!!

First ensure that Thunderbird is closed. Then open your home folder. Show hidden files in Nautilus (CTRL + H) and remove ".thunderbird" folder.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall Thunderbird, it depends on how it was installed.  Best thing to do, is use synaptic to completely remove it.

If synaptic is not installed, it can be installed by, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open it, search for Thunderbird, and mark it for complete removal.

Go to Edit --> Account Settings, once the new windows open, click on Account Actions --> Remove Account.  See images below.

[image]

[image]